# Using Accumulative Recursion to Produce the Result of the Given Equation in Python

Tags: python, accumulator

The given equation is:

> [image]

I have tried the following:

```
def eqn_result (n):
    return eqn_result_acc(n,2)

def eqn_result_acc(current_n, sum_so_far):
    if current_n==1:
        return sum_so_far
    else:
        next_p = sum_so_far * current_n
        next_s = sum_so_far + current_n
        return eqn_result_acc(current_n-1, sum_so_far+(next_p/next_s))
```

Any help would be great

Comment: What result did you get?  What did you expect?  What errors, if any?

Comment: When n = 3, I expected 4.5 and got a result of 4

Comment: See my answer.  I just realized that it was your problem.

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
import operator

def foo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1

    l = range(1, n + 1)

    top = sum(l)
    bottom = reduce(operator.mul, l, 1)
    return foo(n - 1) + float(top) / float(bottom)
```

Now if you want to do it with accumulative results, you need to store both addiction and product, something like:

```
def foo(step, n, r, s, p):
    if n == step:
        return r

    s += step + 1
    p *= step + 1
    r += float(s) / float(p)

    return foo(step + 1, n, r, s, p)

def bar(n):
    return foo(0, n, 1, 0, 1)
```

Just for the fun of it, here's a third version, that somehow makes more sense, but it's non-accumulative as it first calculate the sum and product, then decrement them at each step:

```
def foo(n, s, p):
    if n == 0:
        return 1

    return float(s) / float(p) + foo(n - 1, s - n, p / n)

def bar(n):
    l = range(1, n + 1)
    s = sum(l)
    p = 1
    for e in l: p *= e

    return foo(n, s, p)
```

Comment: I understand this method but I am not allowed to use import operator yet. Is there another way to correct my code?

Comment: oh yeah... sorry, the `import` is useless in my second example, in my first example it's only used to make a multiplication of all elements of the list, it could be wrote without it.

Comment: I tried it your way and got the error `expected 4.5, saw 3.83333333333 when n = 3`.

Comment: ouch... indeed... my accumulative version was wrong, it's fixed now :)

Comment: well... that's a recursive function, so that's expected, which step are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I am trying to calculate bar(3)

Comment: err... try to run "import sys; sys.getrecursionlimit()" from you python shell to check your recursion limit. here I can go to step 100 without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

What result did you get?  What did you expect?  What errors, if any?

Could it be that you've been hoisted by integer division?  That second term is `3/2 = 1.5`.  You're using all integers.  You'll need to make them floating point numbers.

Comment: or `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: Since I haven't learnt `from __future__ import division`, I cannot use it. So what part of my program would I have to cast? I am a bit confused since I am new to python.

Comment: Look at float() to convert it.